# GMGridView equivalent in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-emulator, grid

Do we have something like gmgridview equivalent in android.Some library or something that can simulate the same behaviour for android like GMGRIDVIEW do for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an exact version of GMGGridView for Android but here is a similar one that might be helpful:
https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView (I believe it is open source)
Also information about Android's Gridview...
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/
Hope these helps.

Comment: yes i have gone through Draggable gridview and it is open source too but when i try it for a complete layout then it goes off can you help we with a sample of having a custom layout as draggable??